# Marketing Cloud Error on Full Join: Cannot insert a NULL value into a non-nullable column

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am attempting to combine two data extensions in SFMC. Whenever I try to do a full join I get the error "Cannot insert a NULL value into a non-nullable column." If I do a right/left join or an inner join I do not get this error.

The only field that is non-nullable is the email address. The rest are nullable with default values. I have the code below. Thanks!

```
SELECT a. Email, a. Category, a.ExpiresOn, a. FirstName, a. LastName, a. Life, a. ZipCode, a. VisualID, a. MembershipType, b. OptEvents, b. OptFamilyPrograms, b. OptStudentTeacherPrograms, b. OptHumanResources, b. OptAcademicEngagement, b. OptTeenPrograms
FROM [Daily - RE Master] a 
FULL JOIN ent.[All Subscribers Master] b 
    ON a.Email = b.Email
```

Comment: You probably have records without email in at least one of the DEs, which you could filter out through `WHERE email is not NULL and email != ''` using the respective a or b alias, depending on where this occurs. Likely a. It would be expected from the FULL JOIN to return such records as NULL, so the error is plausible, what's indeed surprising is that LEFT and RIGHT JOIN would return them as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have actually tried that before and it hasn't helped. The LEFT and RIGHT joins aren't returning errors. I'm trying to get the two lists to combine regardless of matching, so I guess I'm not sure if I'm going about it completely wrong...

Comment: I had a typo, wanted to say what's surprising is that LEFT and RIGHT would NOT return them. No matter - suggestion, please edit your post be more precise about your two tables and expected result - I was assuming email is a common key in both tables?  What do you mean by "combine", when now you say "regardless of matching"? Do you want to randomly assign rows from table b to table a and don't care about matching email? That can be done with cross apply, if that's what you want, I can share a code example.